# Is it possible to combine the secrets for two docker registries used by kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have the following two secrets for two different docker registries:

secret1-registry.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: somevalue1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: metadata1
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

secret2-registry.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: somevalue2
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: metadata2
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Is it possible to combine the two secrets?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually combine, the .dockerconfigjson field should be a base64-encoded representation of the combined Docker configuration JSON. To create the base64-encoded data, you can use a tool like echo -n '<json_data>' | base64 -w 0.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: combined_base64_encoded_data
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: combined-docker-secrets
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

You can also use kubectl commands to create the combined secret. Assuming you have the content of somevalue1 and somevalue2 as actual Docker configuration JSONs.

```
# Base64 encode the combined Docker configuration JSON
combined_data=$(echo -n '{"auths":{"registry1":{"auth":"somevalue1"},"registry2":{"auth":"somevalue2"}}}' | base64 -w 0)

# Create the combined secret
kubectl create secret generic combined-docker-secrets \
  --from-literal=.dockerconfigjson=$combined_data \
  --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to combine those secrets? When you specify an imagePullSecret for a Deployment or a similar resource, you can provide a list of imagePullSecrets to use during the container image pull phase.

Answer (score 0):

A possible work-around to consider is specifying multiple image pull secrets on the pod specification as described here

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod

For example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp1
          image: myreg1.example.org/myapp1:v2.0.0
          ..
        - name: myapp2
          image: myreg2.example.org/myapp2:v2.0.0
          ..
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: reg-creds-myreg1
        - name: reg-creds-myreg2
```